# Materials that will block water but allow sound to travel through without being muffled

Tags: materials, waterproofing, liquid, sound

I am in a fraternity at my college. We would like to host a paint party but are worried about our speakers getting damaged. The paint used is water based, so very thin. The paint is made using waterbottles filled with paint powder, a hole is punched in the cap so that water can be sprayed out at low pressure. We have some high end speakers that we are worried about damaging. Last time this was tried was several years ago. Large garbage bags were put over the speakers which obviously protected them but significantly muffled the sound quality.

Are there any materials, perhaps a screen of some kind, that would protect the speakers from light splash but not significantly impact sound quality?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is as follows.

Get you the *cheap, thin* white trashbags as used to line kitchen wastebaskets. This material will attenuate sound very little.

Now note that what attenuation there will be is in the high frequencies. With the protective bag covering one speaker and no bag on the other, listen to both, note the attenuation of the highs on the bagged speaker, and *turn up the treble control on the stereo amp* until the bagged speaker sounds as bright as the unbagged speaker did before turning up the treble. You have now *equalized* the speakers to account for the bag material.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are high-end speakers you presumably want high-end results, which requires measurement and analysis.

Play pink noise through the uncovered speaker and record it with a measurement-grade microphone. Cover the speaker with your garbage bag and record it from the same position in the room.

Using analysis software such as Audacity, plot the FFT of the before and after recordings, and determine the difference at various frequencies (mostly high frequencies will be affected).

Get a graphical EQ and boost the high frequencies by the difference measured. Re-measure and confirm.

Note that the garbage bag covered with paint, booze, or other party fluids will impose a different transmission loss than just a garbage bag, so the accuracy of your correction will decline as the party progresses.